# Filtering data in angularjs using checkbox and show inside textbox in comma separated list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm showing 8 checkboxes using ng-repeat and filtering the data by getting only checked values and showing them in comma separated list using another ng-repeat. But I need to show the exact filtered comma separated string in a textbox and update just as it is getting updated inside ng-repeat.

```
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="tooth in teeth">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tooth.checked" ng-change="upperRight()" /> {{tooth.id}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span ng-repeat="toothObj in teeth | filter:{ checked: true }">{{toothObj.id}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="selectedTeeth" />
        </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.teeth = [
  { id: 1, checked: false }, 
  { id: 2, checked: false }, 
  { id: 3, checked: false }, 
  { id: 4, checked: false }, 
  { id: 5, checked: false }, 
  { id: 6, checked: false }, 
  { id: 7, checked: false }, 
  { id: 8, checked: false }
];
```

Here I added it in plunker for better understanding [Plunker URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEvZ2U2HNROYu8Nrk9EE?p=info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it in following way

My controller

```
$scope.teethUR = [{ id: 1, checked: false }, { id: 2, checked: false }, { id: 3, checked: false }, { id: 4, checked: false }, { id: 5, checked: false }, { id: 6, checked: false }, { id: 7, checked: false }, { id: 8, checked: false }];
$scope.upperRight = function () {
    $scope.URSelected = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.teethUR.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.teethUR[i].checked == true) {
            if ($scope.URSelected == "") {
                $scope.URSelected = $scope.teethUR[i].id;
            } else {
                $scope.URSelected = $scope.URSelected + ", " + $scope.teethUR[i].id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And HTML

```
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="tooth in teethUR">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tooth.checked" ng-change="upperRight()" /> {{tooth.id}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" ng-model="URSelected" class="form-control" />
        </div>
```

Have a look at the working code here [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEvZ2U2HNROYu8Nrk9EE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gApGfMq4g31BBhJzKSR1?p=preview)

You can set up two-way binding between the textbox and the checkboxes. When you click the checkboxes, the text box is updated, and when you update the text box, the check boxes are updated.

First, setup two watches: one that watches teeth, and another that watches selectedTeeth:

```
  $scope.$watch ('teeth', function(newVal) {
    $scope.selectedTeeth = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < newVal.length; ++i) {
      if (newVal[i].checked) 
        $scope.selectedTeeth.push(newVal[i].id);
    }
  }, true);

  $scope.$watch('selectedTeeth', function(newVal) {
      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.teeth.length; ++j) {
        var tooth = $scope.teeth[j];
        if (newVal.indexOf(tooth.id) >= 0) {
          tooth.checked = true;
        }
        else {
          tooth.checked = false;
        }

      }
  }, true);
```

Next set up a ngModel directive, that provides a formatter and a parser to marshal between the 'teeth' and 'selectedTeeth' and vice versa:

```
app.directive ('teethTextBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: { ngModel: '=' },
    link:function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value) {

           return value;
      });

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
           var numbers = [];
           var tmp = value.split(',');
           for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) {
             numbers.push(parseInt(tmp[i]))
           }
           return numbers;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Hook up the directives in the HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="tooth in teeth">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tooth.checked" ng-change="upperRight()" /> {{tooth.id}}
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" ng-model="selectedTeeth" teeth-text-box />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Sir. I up voted your answer as its working fine. But I will go with my solution as it seems a lot simpler and easy to implement. Anyways, I learned some interesting and new things from your answer too. :)